# Its possible to use version 15 for Paypal?

Tags: android, facebook, paypal

Hello i´m having errors in Android because that Facebook SDK is minimum 15 and Paypal is minimum 16

This is the error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2] C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\flappyfalcon\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.paypal.sdk\paypal-android-sdk\2.14.2\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments" to force usage
```

This is my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5]'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    //You have to add this line
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'
    compile project(':adcolony')
}
```

Comment: You could attempt to change the `minSdkVersion` on your downloaded library. While this "could" work, most vendor set their `minSdkVersion` as low as possible (to ensure the most consumers reached). Also note that, as that application deals directly with money, you should always ensure you have the latest resources, so as to protect YOUR costumer, from possible failures in OTHERs applications. If a "fix" wont solve your problem, consider increasing your minimum SDK version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is just showing that what you used Library in your project is :

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'
}
```

it is supported for only minimum sdk version 16.

and at a starting of app level Build.gradel you defile 15 as a minimum sdk so it's just because of conflict of minimum sdk.

Solution : 
         Just Replace your minimum sdk version 15 to 16 that's it.

Let me know if it is not working